# How to add two value to Access-Control-Allow-Origin

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, cors

I have API project using .net4.5 and create an APIs to consume from multiple websites.

I have two website

- https://example1.com
- https://example2.com

in the web.config I try to add these 2 value together in Access-Control-Allow-Origin:

```
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="https://example1.com ,https://example2.com"/>
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Credentials" value="true"/>
     <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="true"/>
```

but it is not working. Error message:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'API' from origin '`https://example1.com`' has been blocked by CORS policy: The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header contains multiple values 'https://example1.com , https://example2.com', but only one is allowed.

Note: I use .net4.5

I try to add these 2 value in Access-Control-Allow-Origin

Comment: The `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header can only contain a single origin value or the wildcard (`*`). Instead of "manually" implementing CORS in your `web.config`, why don't you rely on .NET's CORS middleware instead? It will allow you to configure an allowlist of origins easily.